# PutSQL date format error cannot convert date value to timestamp

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using apache nifi to query an Teradata Database using custom SQL script and store the result in an Oracle Database. 

The dataflow i used in nifi is as follows:

1. ExecuteSQL (execute SQL Select script)
2. UpdateRecord (to add 3 additional columns not included in original sql select which are id, created_dt and updated_dt)
3. ConvertAvroToJson (nothing special here just to convert Avro to
   Json)
4. ConvertJsonToSQL (nothing special here just to convert Json to SQL
   INSERT query)
5. UpdateAttribute (which formats created_dt and updated_dt using the
   following format
   ${sql.args.39.value:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):format("yyyy-MM-dd")} and
   ${sql.args.40.value:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):format("yyyy-MM-dd")} )
6. PutSQL (to execute the insert statement created from previous flow)

Step 6 is where i encounter the error below and i've tried for a couple of resources online and it didn't help. 
For a very simple use case it took me a couple of days to figure it out and i think am getting closer but I need some advice on how to properly configure and insert a data on a date column.

ERROR LOG

```
 due to java.sql.SQLDataException: The value of the sql.args.39.value is '2019-12-12', which cannot be converted to a timestamp; routing to failure: java.sql.SQLDataException: The value of the sql.args.39.value is '2019-12-12', which cannot be converted to a timestamp
```

**DB Schema** 
created_dt DATE
updated_dt DATE

**UpdateAttribute Outgoing Data**
  "created_dt" : "2019-12-12",
  "updated_dt" : "2019-12-12"

sql.args.39.type
93
sql.args.39.value
2019-12-12

Comment: What was the solution to this? Been trying to resolve my issue for 10 hours

Answer (score 0):

Cast your value inside of the query itself, not by the UpdateAttribute processor. It will be treated as a string. For example,

```
INSERT INTO Table (crea_dt, ...)
VALUES (${crea_dt:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):format("yyyy-MM-dd")}, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i was actually thinking of doing that but I don't know how to insert the cast on the INSERT query. Any suggestions on how I might do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of step 5, use UpdateAtribute to change sql.args.39.type to 91.
93 is TIMESTAMP, you need DATE type.

For more information, you may read more about [java.sql.types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.sql.types?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding time "00:00:00" to the date as string to make it a timestamp, something like `${sql.args.39.value:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):format("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00")}`